# OpenVPN - Routing from one VPN into another

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, routing, openvpn

I have the following situation. I have a root server, which acts as a *VPN server* for my company network **and** as a *VPN client* to multiple customer-networks. Every seperate connection works (I can ping anyone from my root server, and my root server can be pinged from the corresponding networks).

But now I want the clients in my company network to be able to access all the customers computers, but the customers shouldn't be able to access me and each other. Is that possible?

Example:

- My PC has the IP 10.8.0.11 and is in the net 10.8.0.0/24.
- My customers server has the IP 10.9.0.11 and is in the net 10.9.0.0/24.

My PC now has the following entry in the routing table:

```
10.9.0.0 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.1 [...]
```

And my root server (10.8.0.1) has the following entry:

```
10.9.0.0 255.255.255.0 10.9.0.1 [...]
```

The customers VPN server (10.9.0.1) knows nothing about my net. I can ping everyone on my root-server, and everyone can ping my root server (with the according address). But my PC cannot reach my customers server. I have routing installed on my root server (Windows Server 2008 R2) and it is up and running.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: From where comes your route `10.9.0.0 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.1` on your PC ? did you setup it by yourself ? seems it is not a valid route because the gateway for subnet 10.9.0.0/24 seems to be 10.9.0.1

Comment: It comes from OpenVPN *push "route 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.0"* in the server config. Shouldn't 10.8.0.1 be the gateway for the 10.9.0.0 network, for computers in the 10.8.0.0 network?

Comment: No, to me gateway for 10.9.0.0/24 network should be 10.9.0.1...try this...or ask you this question : is gateway 10.8.0.1 able to route 10.9.0.0/24 subnet (have a look at the routing table of gateway 10.8.0.1) ?

Comment: Yes, 10.8.0.1 is a root server, which has routing installed and should route those two networks. Let me try the other gatweway.

Comment: No, that doens't work either.

Comment: can you send the result of a traceroute to 10.9.0.11 from your pc and from your root server ?

Comment: Are you changing the default gateway when you connect to the VPN?  If not then you may need to push some routes to both VPNs for the other VPN.  Really we need more information though.  Perhaps your VPN server configs, and the route table on the VPN server, and the route table on both clients when they are connected to the VPN.

Comment: @Zoredache You are correct! Looked with wireshark, and the ping packet gets roututed to the 10.9.0.0/24 network correctly. However, it doesn't find the way back. I'll need to talk to the administrator of the customer VPN to let me push the route to his server for the 10.8.0.0/24 network. You can create an answer and I'll upvote and accept :)

Comment: @Zoredache PS: You saved christmas :D